# How do I get axes to show in when plotting via pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to visualize some data with matplotlib.pyplot, but no axes are showing.  I'm looking for a result similar to this, with axes and indexes on the axes:

[image: axes]

What I'm getting as a result is this:

[image: no axes]

Here's the code I'm writing:

```html
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import glob
import json

NAME = os.path.basename(__file__)
print(f"Program \"{NAME}\" started.")

PATTERN = "Deliverables\\*_maint.txt"
METRICS = "metrics.json"

with open(METRICS, "r") as filey:
    DATA = json.loads(filey.read())

report = glob.glob(PATTERN)[0]
with open(report, "r") as filey:
    report_content = filey.read()

for item in DATA:
    hits = report_content.count(item)
    DATA[item]["in final report"] = hits
    DATA.update()

for item in DATA:
    docs = []
    hits = []
    for doc in DATA[item]:
        docs.append(doc)
        hits.append(DATA[item][doc])
    fig = plt.figure()
    x = np.arange(len(docs))
    ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
    ax.set_title("Number of search results by doctype")
    ax.set_xticks(x)
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 50, 10))
    ax.bar(docs, hits)
    plt.show()
    input()


print(f"Program \"{NAME}\" complete.")
```

EDIT:  Forgot example data:  I've included it below:

```html
{"j": {"a": 0, "d": 0, "c": 4, "e": 20, "f": 10, "g": 0}, "h:": {"a": 0, "d": 0, "c": 0, "e": 2, "f": 0, "g": 0}, "i": {"a": 13, "d": 0, "c": 0, "e": 0, "f": 0, "g": 0}, "k": {"a": 6, "d": 0, "c": 0, "e": 0, "f": 0, "g": 0}, "n": {"a": 0, "d": 9, "c": 1, "e": 5, "f": 3, "g": 0}, "o": {"a": 0, "d": 0, "c": 0, "e": 0, "f": 0, "g": 0}, "p": {"a": 0, "d": 24, "c": 0, "e": 0, "f": 0, "g": 0}, "q": {"a": 0, "d": 0, "c": 0, "e": 0, "f": 0, "g": 0}, "r": {"a": 0, "d": 0, "c": 0, "e": 0, "f": 0, "g": 0}, "s": {"a": 0, "d": 0, "c": 0, "e": 1, "f": 1, "g": 0}, "t": {"a": 0, "d": 0, "c": 0, "e": 10, "f": 9, "g": 0}, "m": {"a": 2, "d": 0, "c": 0, "e": 13, "f": 19, "g": 0}, "l": {"a": 0, "d": 0, "c": 0, "e": 1, "f": 2, "g": 0}, "b": {"a": 0, "d": 0, "c": 0, "e": 15, "f": 0, "g": 0}}
```

Comment: Your [mre] should include a minimal example of `DATA` - enough to test your code and our solutions. Better yet, a minimal example of `docs` and `hits` for one of the outer loop iterations.

Comment: Thanks - I've added example data to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap

```html
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
```

for the following:

```html
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
```